# bootstrap tooltip shifted right

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

All was nice, but in one moment tooltips become crazy.

http://jsfiddle.net/AJkJa/10/ tooltip should be near of text, but it's on right border.
if i set small width, it's will be on this width from text.

what i'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div rel="tooltip" data-original-title="tooltip" data-placement="right">hover me. tooltip should be here.but it's shifted right</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tooltip does not "became crazy"! When you place it `right` it will find the end of the container, and because a `<div>` renders as `display:block` it will find the end far away.

A Simple way to prove it is given a `background-color:red` to that div and you will see what's going on.

To have only the **hover me** getting the hover effect, give the tooltip only to it, like:

```
<div>
  <span rel="tooltip" data-original-title="tooltip" data-placement="right">hover me</span>. 
  tooltip should be here.but it's shifted right
</div>
```

updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/AJkJa/11/

Answer (score 0):

The div extends to the [whole available space](http://s.gullipics.com/image/1/5/m/59hli2-jh80wa-y24s/tooltip.png). If you give a width-, or a display-style it fits.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div rel="tooltip" data-original-title="tooltip" style="width:350px;" data-placement="right">hover me. tooltip should be here.but it's shifted right</div>
</body>
</html>
```