# gwtbootstrap3 tooltip at wrong place for pagination

Tags: gwt, pagination, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, gwtbootstrap3

[image]

This is what happens when you hover the very left item of the pagination or the very right one.

### What I need to have:

That the tooltip is stick to the corresponding element when I hover it.

### My code:

```
back = new AnchorListItem();
back.setText("Vorherige Aufgabe");
back.setIcon(IconType.CHEVRON_LEFT);
back.setIconPosition(IconPosition.LEFT);
bback.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {  ...some code... }
if (some_Condition){
    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip(back, "Diese Aufgabe hat nur eine Teilaufgabe");
    tooltip.setPlacement(Placement.TOP);
}
pagination.add(back);

.
. 
.
some code
.
.
.
next = new AnchorListItem();
next.setText("Nächste Aufgabe");
next.setIcon(IconType.CHEVRON_RIGHT);
next.setIconPosition(IconPosition.RIGHT);
next.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { ...some code... }
if (some_Condition){
    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip(next, "Diese Aufgabe hat nur eine Teilaufgabe");
    tooltip.setPlacement(Placement.TOP);
}
pagination.add(next);
```

Setting the Placement differently changes only in which direction the tooltip it placed, but not the origin.

I would be thankful for any hints :)

Comment: Very possible to be wrong here, but I vaguely recall that you need to call init() on the tooltip can you try this?

Comment: yes I tried this before, it didn't change anything
my tooltips are initialized manually anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, don't ask how I found it nor why it works, but the solution is:

Add `float: left;` style to `AnchorListItem`'s `<li>` element inside `Pagination`.

You can do it in your stylesheet:

```
.pagination li {
    float: left;
}
```

Surprisingly, this is also an answer to this problem: [bootstrap tooltip shifted right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787454/bootstrap-tooltip-shifted-right) ;)

Comment: wow this is strange, you can even use float: left OR float:right it both works!
Thank you very much!